# How to get data from function image_line_segment_detector in R or Python

Tags: python, r, dataframe, image-processing

I would like to analyse an image with many lines. The aim is to know the orientation and direction of the lines and check if there are parallel.

I used the function `image.LineSegmentDetector` from the package `library(image.LineSegmentDetector)` to be able to extract segments from the image. I obtain a LSD class that I cannot convert in data frame or another type. How to extract the width by example?

In R:

```
linesegments <- image_line_segment_detector(image@grey * 255)
class(linesegments)
> class(linesegments)
[1] "lsd"
> head(linesegments)
$lines
          x1      y1     x2      y2    width            p    -log_nfa
 [1,] 331.25  914.00 315.00  914.00 3.983996 0.1250000000  10.9979604
 [2,] 127.50  680.25  26.25  681.50 5.116417 0.1250000000 146.9276900
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a list with a data.frame in it?

If `linesegments$lines` is a data.frame, then so:

```r
linesegments$lines$width
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution I found:

```
> typeof(linesegments)
[1] "list"
> class(linesegments)
[1] "lsd"
matrix <- linesegments$lines
> typeof(matrix)
[1] "double"
> class(matrix)
[1] "matrix" "array"
```

Then as usual for matrix to get the column 5:

```
width <- matrix[,5]
```

3